# I get a error while publishing a app. The error is property json does not exist on type object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

when I try to test the app in Ionic serve command, I didn't get any error. But when i try to publish the app, I get the error as "property json does not exist on type object" . The error takes place during the transpile stage:

[image: This What Im Getting]

How to solve this problem? I tried with every possibility, but i didn't get my problem solved.

**Home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WeatherProvider } from '../../providers/weather/weather';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
//import { Response } from '@angular/http';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   weather:any;
   location:{
        city:string,
        state:string
    }

   constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController, 
      private weatherProvider:WeatherProvider,
      private storage: Storage) {

      }

      ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.storage.get('location').then((val)=>{
            if(val!=null){
                this.location = JSON.parse(val);
            }else{
                this.location = {
                    city: 'Chennai',
                    state: 'TN'
                }
            }


        this.weatherProvider.getWeather(this.location.city,this.location.state)
       // .map((res: Response) => res.json() )
            .subscribe(weather => {
                this.weather =  weather.current_observation;

        });

        });

      }

    }
```

**Weather.ts**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    //import { Response } from '@angular/http';
    //import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    //import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class WeatherProvider {
        apiKey = '6d3243fb22b01d0c';
        url;

      constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello WeatherProvider Provider');
        this.url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+this.apiKey+'/conditions/q';
      }
      getWeather(city, state){
        return this.http.get(this.url+'/'+state+'/'+city+'.json')
            // .map(res => res.json());
        // .map((res: Response) => res.json() );

      }
    }
```

Comment: are you using angular 5?

Comment: I dont know bro just followed tutorial from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs2n_poLarc)

Comment: Look in your package.json and see what version you're using.

Comment: Yes bro Im using Angular 5.0.3 version

Comment: Please don't call me "bro".  Does Amy look like a man's name?

Comment: OK cool Sis.I didn't look up the name

Comment: @Perinban: it may be helpful for you to know that "brother" and "sister" (and variations thereof) are too familiar for most English speakers (as well as an opportunity to get people's gender wrong). I suggest you avoid them here.

Comment: @halfer ok friend

Comment: @Perinban: it is probably better to avoid that one too. It implies a connection that one does not have, and the listener may find it presumptuous. For some English speakers, it additionally can project a menacing tone, as it is often used ironically (see _Pulp Fiction_, _The Godfather_, etc). Is this helpful?

Comment: @halfer ok halfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is all about typing. So you should state the type of object you'are receiving from the method getWeather. Start by creating a class Weather at the end of home.ts (look below)

```
class Weather {
  current_observation: string;
}
```

and make this change:

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(this.location.city,this.location.state)
       // .map((res: Response) => res.json() )
            .subscribe((weather: Weather) => {
                this.weather =  weather.current_observation;

        });
        });
      }
```

Comment: There is one in that. Im returning a json object. How it can be called as string in the class?

Comment: I can't remember why I made that decision but sure if you return an object instead of a  string just add a typing like this   current_observation: any;

Comment: Other one. Im going to develop an Indoor Navigation App in Ionic. How to use Ionic storage to store the Map in the local and create a search button which searches the Map. Is there any search API I could use for that?

Answer (score 1):

ionViewWillEnter(){

```
this.storage.get('location').then((val) => {
  if(val != null){
    this.location = JSON.parse(val);
  } else{
    this.location ={
      city: 'miami',
      state: 'FL'
    }
  }
```

//Try below code
      this.weatherprovider.getweather(this.location.city, this.location.state).subscribe(result => {
        let weather:any = result;
        this.weather = weather.current_observation;
        console.log(this.weather);
      });
    });
  }

Comment: ionViewWillEnter(){

    this.storage.get('location').then((val) => {
      if(val != null){
        this.location = JSON.parse(val);
      } else{
        this.location ={
          city: 'miami',
          state: 'FL'
        }
      }
      this.weatherprovider.getweather(this.location.city, this.location.state).subscribe(result => {
        let weather:any = result;
        this.weather = weather.current_observation;
        console.log(this.weather);
      });
    });
  }

Comment: There is an edit button, that you can use to improve answer quality. Cheers!